# When tabbar is hidden it leaves a black space

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

When I call `tabbar.isHidden = true` in `viewWillAppear` it leaves a black space. No matter what I try, nothing is helping. I have tride `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed, tried to change the tabbar size to 0 and so on. In another project of mine it works, but not in this one.

Anyone have a solution?

Oh, I am not using Storyboard, I do everything programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

5 minutes later, here we are again ...
I have found the solution!

I called `tabBar.isTranslucent = false` in my MainTabController. When calling `tabBar.isHidden = true` in my other views, it did only hide the tabBar but did not make the translucent part go away.

So yea, I hope you understand the solution, if you should ever run into a similar problem, make sure to check if you call `isTranslucent` anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are redirecting from view controller A to B, when you are creating instance of view controller B (Inside view controller A) to redirect. Try like this it worked for me.

```
let vc = IKSikSearchViewController()
vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```